# Can't access Synapse Lake Database from Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I created a Synapse Lake dabase using the Consumer Goods template, the path in the linked service is `forsynapse1/ConsumerGoods_fdw`, I don't have problems when I try to read some tables from Synapse like this

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM `ConsumerGoods_fdw`.`Channel`")
```

With the DESCRIBE DATABASE I get the location `abfss://contfrsynapse@stgacctst1.dfs.core.windows.net/ConsumerGoods_fdw`

But, if I try to read like this

```
dd=spark.read.load("abfss://contfrsynapse@stgacctst1.dfs.core.windows.net/ConsumerGoods_fdw")
```

I get an error

```
Path does not exist: abfss://contfrsynapse@stgacctst1.dfs.core.windows.net/ConsumerGoods_fdw
```

Also tried to read it in Databricks and I get this error

```
[PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist
```

Then, I checked the path and noticed that there was no file for the lake database, so I would like to know if there is a way to read the information from the Synapse lake database with Databricks, or where I could find the lake database file or folder

Answer (score 0):

In Synapse, the database and its tables are logical entities that are managed within the Synapse workspace. The actual data files associated with the tables are stored in the underlying Azure Data Lake Storage.

For example I have created a table in Azure synapse Dedicated Pool.

[image]

And then I tried reading the table in the databricks.
To establish the connection between the Azure databricks and Azure synapse you can use the below comands.

**Set up the storage account access key in the notebook session conf.**

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.newadlsgen229may.dfs.core.windows.net",
"XXXXXXXXXXXStorageaccounaccesskeyXXXXXXX")
```

To establish connection between Azure synapse and Databricks.

```
%scala

val  jdbcHostname ="wkpspcsynpanalytics.sql.azuresynapse.net"

val  jdbcPort= 1433

val  jdbcDatabase= "ddpool"

val  jdbcUrl =s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

  

import  java.util.Properties

val  connectionProperties = new  Properties()

  

connectionProperties.put("user","sqladminuser@wkpspcsynpanalytics")

connectionProperties.put("password","Welcome@1")
```

**Reading the Synapse Table**

```
%scala

val  df= spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl,"products",connectionProperties)
```

**Display the dataframe(Table)**

```
%scala

display(df)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]